# Regarding the definition of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $R^n$: Definition vs. Intuition

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-sets

> *Definition*: $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if $\forall  \epsilon > 0, \exists$ an open set $G \ni E \subset G $ and $\mu^*|G-E| < \epsilon$
>
> *Idea*: $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if $\exists $ a set $H$ of type $G_{\delta} \ni E \subset H $ and $\mu^*|H-E|=0$

*Definition* is what we were given in class. *Idea* is something I was thinking about when the professor was giving us *Definition*. Based on my understanding of *Definition*, I feel like *Idea* should be another way of defining a Lebesgue measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R^n}.$ But this is just based on intuition. I couldn't think of counterexamples so I tried to prove:

> $\forall  \epsilon > 0, \exists$ an open set $G \ni E \subset G $ and $\mu^*|G-E| < \epsilon \iff \exists $ a set $H$ of type $G_{\delta} \ni E \subset H $ and $\mu^*|H-E|=0$

$\implies$ Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}.$ Then $\exists $ open sets $G_k \ni E \subset G_k$ and $\mu^*|G_k - E| < \frac{1}{k}.$ Take $H = \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} G_K$. Then $H$ is of type $G_{\delta}$ and $E \subset H.$ Since $H - E \subset G_k - E$ it follows $0 \leq \mu^*|H - E| \leq \mu^*|G_k - E| < \frac{1}{k}$. So $\mu^*|H - E|=0.$

$\impliedby$Let $E \subset \mathbb{R^n}.$ Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We know that $\exists $ an open set $G_{\alpha} \ni E \subset G_{\alpha}$ and $\mu^*|G_{\alpha}| \leq \mu^*|E| + \epsilon$. Consider $G = H \cap G_{\alpha}=\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}(G_k \cap G_{\alpha})$. Then $G$ is open and $E \subset G$. Since $G-E = (H \cap G_{\alpha}) - E \subset H - E$, we have that $\mu^*|G-E| \leq \mu^*|H-E| = 0 < \epsilon.$

Could someone let me know if this is correct and if not, give me counterexamples?

Comment: This seems wrong, mainly because if $H$ is $G_\delta$ and $G_\alpha$ is open then there is no guarantee $G$ is open. In fact, you've assumed the existence of an open set $G_\alpha \supset E$ such that $\mu^*|G_\alpha - E| < \epsilon$ but that's exactly what you want to show. EDIT: Your question also appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906363/show-a-is-a-lebesgue-measurable-set-iff-there-exists-f-sigma-set-such-th).

Comment: I should add that the other way of seeing that something is awry is that you've proved something even stronger; that there exists $G$ with the property $\mu^*|G - E| = 0$, not just smaller than $\epsilon$. But this is not possible, for instance if $n = 1$ and $E = [0, 1]$; every open set containing the closed unit interval contains a small ball at $0$ and $1$ and therefore $\mu^*|G - E| > 0$ for all $G$.

Comment: Oh gosh right, I just saw my mistake, thank you. Let me fix it. But are the two definitions still equivalent?

Comment: Yes - the top answer in the link shows your result and the analogous result for $F_\sigma$ sets too.

Comment: Also, I think your first comment is not entirely correct. For every set E in $\mathbb{R^n}$ (Lebesgue measurable or not) and for any given epsilon there is some open set G in $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that E is a subset of G and the outer measure of G is less than or equal to the outer measure of E plus epsilon. This is not implying that $\mu^*|G-E| < \epsilon$. But it would imply it if E were Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Oh right yes you're right.